# MySQL update updates tables with ones not with specified values

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

So, I've made a html form, where button is called "submit". Then I made PHP code, which responds to that.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $subject = isset($_POST['subject']);
    $topic = isset($_POST['topic']);
    $message = isset($_POST['message']);
    $cislo = '1';

    $stmt1 = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users(subject,topic,message,hasticket) VALUES(:subject, :topic, :message, :hasticket) WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt1->bindparam(":subject",$subject);
    $stmt1->bindparam(":topic",$topic);
    $stmt1->bindparam(":message",$message);
    $stmt1->bindparam(":hasticket", $cislo);
    $stmt1->bindparam(":uid", $_SESSION['userSession']);
    $stmt1->execute();

}
```

The code doesn't work and I don't know why. When I open the error log of Apache 2, it says:

```
[Sat Aug 12 09:51:48.052751 2017] [:error] [pid 9146] [client 89.176.222.111:50574] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(subject,topic,message,hasticket) VALUES('1', '1', '1', '1') WHERE userID='20'' at line 1 in /var/www/html/cross/panel/ticket/index.php:27\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/cross/panel/ticket/index.php(27): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/cross/panel/ticket/index.php on line 27, referer: http://templehost.tk/cross/panel/ticket/
```

I have tried everything to fix it, but I don't know how. The clue is probably that it puts ones everywhere.

```
(subject,topic,message,hasticket) VALUES('1', '1', '1', '1')
```

Comment: you need to check the `update syntax`    `UPDATE tbl_users set subject=:subject,topic=:topic,message=:message,hasticket=:hasticket WHERE userID=:uid`

Comment: Please don't remove your question once answered - the idea is it may be helpful for future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `update` `syntax` should be like this

```
UPDATE tbl_users set 
           subject=:subject,
           topic=:topic,
           message=:message,
           hasticket=:hasticket 
WHERE userID=:uid
```

**1st :** `$subject = isset($_POST['subject']);` `isset` i will  return `boolean value` `true or false` so your storing `boolean` value in `$subject` variable . so change this to  `$subject = isset($_POST['subject'])? $_POST['subject']:'';`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are taking the values from HTML form incorrectly.

replace

```
  $subject = isset($_POST['subject']);
    $topic = isset($_POST['topic']);
    $message = isset($_POST['message']);
```

with

```
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
```

Second, Your update query is incorrect.

```
$stmt1 = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users set subject=:subject,
topic=:topic, message=:message, hasticket=:hasticket WHERE userID=:uid");
```

Further reading recommended for you: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: This query works, but it updates rows with ones -
 https://upload.hicoria.com/files/x57x1dqj.PNG

Comment: show your database table structure. what is the data type of all these columns?

Comment: try to `echo` (print) your variables as what value is coming in them.



`echo  $subject;` likewise

Comment: What do you see when you do this much only?

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $subject = isset($_POST['subject']);
    $topic = isset($_POST['topic']);
    $message = isset($_POST['message']);
    $cislo = '1';

echo $message; 
echo $subject; 
echo $topic;

}`

Comment: It updates every row with 1 insted of hasticket. And it also breaks the whole html

Comment: no
there's something wrong with the values that are coming from your HTML page. 
Post your entire HTML form code also.

Comment: `$subject = isset($_POST['subject']);` `isset` i will  return `boolean value` `true or false` so your storing `boolean` value in `$subject` variable . so change this to  `$subject = isset($_POST['subject'])? $_POST['subject']:'';`

Comment: Glad it help you @RondomMC